# Firestore find a document matching a field in firestore in a collection in a collection

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have this collection referrals. Inside referrals are a bunch of documents. Each document represents a referral code. Within each of those documents is a usage collection. Within each usage collection I have a bunch of documents. Each of those documents is a referral usage. I need to find where the document associated with a specific userId. Here is the structure of the db:

```
*Collection* Referrals ->
    *Documents* (Referral Codes)->
        *Collection* Usage ->
            *Documents* (Referral Code Usages) 
                *field:* Owner_ID
```

I need to search all of these referral code usages documents for a specific Owner_ID. Here is what I have so far:

```
      let referralUsageId = await admin
      .firestore
      .collection('Databases/' + storage + '/Referrals')
    //get all referral code docs?
    //Then search through all their referral  code usages for a specific Owner_ID
```

Comment: It looks to me that your query doesn't match your database structure.  Could you make sure that they do?  I don't see a collection called "Databases" anywhere.

Comment: Hello Doug thank you for the reply, the Databases collection can basically be ignored for this purpose. I don't fully understand what it does or why it is there. My part basically begins on referrals.

Comment: That's kind of the problem, isn't it?  If you don't see or know about the Databases collection, how can you be sure it's important for they query here?

Comment: I agree with Doug in the comment that this 'Databases' collection may be an issue. Can you share your complete firestore structure? That would help us build a more refined example that has better chances on addressing inquiry you have.